# $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4\}$. Consider the events $E = \{1,2\}, F = \{1,3\}$ and $G = \{3,4\}$,Which option correct regarding independence of events?

Tags: probability, independence

Let $P \ $ be a probability function that assigns the same weight to each of the points of the sample
space $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4\}$. Consider the events $E = \{1,2\}, F = \{1,3\}$ and $G = \{3,4\}$. Which of the following statement(s) is (are) true?

$(1)$ $E$ and $F$ are independent

$(2)$ $E$ and $G$ are independent

$(3)$ $F$ and $G$ are independent

$(4)$ $E$, $F$ and $G$ are independent

I am not sure what they are asking. I know for independence we need to show $P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B)$
but I am not able to understand events here. Does that mean event $E$ is selecting $1$ and $2$?

$P(\text{selecting $1$} )=\dfrac{1}{4}=P(\text{selecting $2$} )$

Therefore $P(E)=\dfrac{1}{16}=P(F)$

But $E\cap F = \{1\}$ therefore $P(E\cap F)=\dfrac{1}{4}\ne P(E)P(F)$. Is it true that they are not independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $ \ $ be a probability function that assigns the same weight to each of the points of the sample space $Ω = \{1,2,3,4\}$.

This make me thinking that if $E = \{1,2\}$ then $P(E) = \frac{1}{2}$ because the probability of choosing one element of $E$ under the assumption above is exactly $\frac{1}{2}$.

To be more clear, if you had a subset $K \subseteq \Omega$ such that $|K| = 3$ then I would think that $P(K) = \frac{3}{4}$ and notice that this assumption is reasonable since if $|K| = 4$ then $K = \Omega$ and $P(K) = P(\Omega) = 1$

Now you can go on checking when $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ and check which answer is true.

Answer (score 3):

No, the event $E$ contains the outcomes $1$ and $2$ of the sample space, so $P(E) = P(\{1\}) + P(\{2\}) = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}$. Otherwise you are correct that you need to check $P(E \cap F) \overset{?}{=} P(E) P(F)$, etc.

Comment: How does the numbers between curly braces tell it is 'OR' condition not 'AND' is there any concept behind it? How did you figure it out?